# TokensRegex Expression for NER tagging

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford's core NLP api to get the NER tags from some text. I have a rule that says that if a noun follows an abbreviation, then that noun should be tagged as PERSON and I am using regexner to implement this rule. In the mapping file, I have two rules

```
(?:[A-Z]\.{0,1}){2,10}\tABBR
( [ {ner:ABBR} ] [ {tag:NN} ] )\tPERSON
```

The \t indicates that there is a tab present at that spot. ABBR indicates an abbreviation. The rule for tagging tokens are abbreviations (the first rule) works correctly but the second rule does not seem to work ie, if a noun follows an abbreviation, then the noun is not being tagged as PERSON. I am wondering what I am doing wrong with the TokensRegex expression here.

Comment: does `{ner:ABBR}` check the tag assigned by the previous rule?